# How to get current process's EPROCESS address in windows x64?

Tags: winapi

As we all know,we can get eprocess address in win32 using the code below.
**And this code works in user mode(ring 3).**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define alloc(a) VirtualAlloc(0,a,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE)
#define freea(a) VirtualFree(a,0,MEM_RELEASE)
typedef struct {
    PVOID   Unknown1;
    PVOID   Unknown2;
    PVOID   Base;
    ULONG   Size;
    ULONG   Flags;
    USHORT  Index;
    USHORT  NameLength;
    USHORT  LoadCount;
    USHORT  PathLength;
    CHAR    ImageName[256];
} SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY, *PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY;
typedef struct {
    ULONG   Count;
    SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY Module[1];
} SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION;
typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
    DWORD ProcessId;
    //  USHORT  CreatorBackTraceIndex;
    UCHAR ObjectTypeNumber;
    UCHAR Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE;
typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG HandleCount; /* Or NumberOfHandles if you prefer. */
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemModuleInformation = 11,
    SystemHandleInformation = 16
} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *_NtQuerySystemInformation)(
    SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,
    PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG SystemInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

void main()
{
    _NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation=(_NtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll"),"NtQuerySystemInformation");
    PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION pmodinf;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION phaninf;
    ULONG len = 0;
    char kname[260] = { 0 };
    PVOID kbase = NULL;
    DWORD cpid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE self = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, NULL, cpid);
    HANDLE self2 = NULL;

    DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcess(), &self2, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, NULL, 0, &len);
    pmodinf = (PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION)alloc(len);
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(pmodinf, len);
    NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, pmodinf, len, &len);

    lstrcpyA(kname, pmodinf->Module[0].ImageName);
    kbase = pmodinf->Module[0].Base;
    printf("kbase:%x\tkname:%s\n", kbase, kname);
    HANDLE hntos = LoadLibraryA(kname);

    len = 4096 * 16 * 16;
//  NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, NULL, 0, &len);
    phaninf = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)alloc(len);
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(phaninf, len);
    NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, phaninf, len, &len);

    for (UINT i = 0; i < phaninf->HandleCount; i++)
    {
        if (phaninf->Handles[i].ProcessId==cpid)
        {
            printf("ObjectType:%d\n", phaninf->Handles[i].ObjectTypeNumber);
            printf("Handle:%x,OpenProcessHandle:%x,DuplicateHandle:%x\n", phaninf->Handles[i].Handle, self,self2);
            puts("");
            if (phaninf->Handles[i].Handle==(USHORT)self)
            {
                puts("=============================");
                printf("OpenProcessHandle\tEProcess Found!0x%x\n", phaninf->Handles[i].Object);
                puts("=============================");
            }
            if (phaninf->Handles[i].Handle == (USHORT)self2)
            {
                puts("=============================");
                printf("DuplicateHandle\tEProcess Found!0x%x\n", phaninf->Handles[i].Object);
                puts("=============================");
            }
        }
    }

    freea(phaninf);
    freea(pmodinf);

}
```

I want to get my process's EPROCESS address in winx64,but i failed. Do not use kernel function PsGetCurrrntProcess! I want my code works in user mode but kernel mode!